# What is the maximum viable text length for a textarea in html?

Tags: html, memory, browser, textarea

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FHTML%2FElements%2Ftextarea) says that the textarea supports an unlimited number of characters. For my use case, I have to create a textarea where a user will paste some CSV/JSON data which can be of any length. Since these CSVs or JSONs can get pretty long, I want to limit the length so that the large text doesn't eat up the entire browser memory. What should be the limit that I can place on my textarea. 
I know it depends on the system specs and browser, but I am having a hard time coming up with this number. I am sorry if this comes out as an opinion based question. But it would be of great help if someone can help with either the number or what should I keep in mind to do a safe estimation for that number.

Comment: The limit is set more by a GET than by the length of data

Comment: @SMAKSS I am not asking how to do it. I am asking what is the maximum value that I can set, which would be safe so that browser doesn't crash.

Comment: @mplungjan I don't get your comment.

Comment: I think you can add as much data as the computer can handle. The limit is when you need to send it to the server